# How to convert string to date or datetime vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net-2010

How can I convert my strings into a date or datetime datatype in vb.net?
These are my strings that are date and time with this format:

```
Dim sDate,sTime String
Dim myDate,myTime,dateToSave as Date

sDate = '11/25/13'
sTime = '16:30:05'
```

I wanted to convert it to a date with this expected output:

```
myDate = '11/25/2013'
myTime = '16:30:05'
dateToSave = '11/25/2013 16:30:05'
```

How can I do this so that I can save it to sql table with datatype of datetime?

Answer (score 2):

Declare `myDate`, `myTime` and `dateToSave` as `DateTime`. Then you can use [`DateTime.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to convert a string into a `DateTime`.

PS: I'm reading the `sql-server` tag in your question. Please remember to pass the values to the database server using parameterized queries - this will save you the next question about how to insert dates and times into the database.

Comment: When I try to set my variables into DateTime, I got some error. My exact string value for myDate is '11/25/13' and when I convert it DateTime.TryParse(myDate, result) and alert result would return nothing.

Comment: I mean it's not working. I could not get an alert when I try to alert it.

Comment: And I mean that *Got some error* and *It's not working* are not proper descriptions that I can use to help you. How about providing additional information on what error you get or in what way it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

Something as simple as `myDate = CDate(sDate & " " & sTime)` will work.  But also, if you're going to insert or update a SQL Server table that has a column with one of the date/time data types, you can just insert the value as is and it will be stored with the proper data type:

```
String.Format("INSERT INTO MyTable (MyDateColumn) VALUES({0})", dDateToSave)
```

Comment: Also, I've noticed you're using single quotes (') in the code you posted; in VB.NET you would use double quotes for string literals: (").

Comment: Nothing happens when I used CDate,,
 dDate = result(8).Substring(0, 8) and then alert this
 msgbox(CDate(dDate))

Answer (score 0):

dim QueryString as string = "Update someTable set someDate = '" & sDate & " " & sTime & "'"

or 
dim datetosave as string = sDate & " " & sTime

dim QueryString as string = "Update someTable set someDate = '" & dateToSave & "'"